# MS-ACCESS: Filter a table, then display in unbound listbox

Tags: database, ms-access

In my form `Main` I am trying to have a push button `Search` display a few columns from `Table` into an unbound listbox (located on form `Main`) after applying a filter. Initially I was using a ComboBox, but I would like to use a listbox that only displays the names of those who are overdue on training. Below is what I had when using a ComboBox, which worked perfectly.

```
Private Sub SearchCheck_Click()
Call Search
End Sub

Sub Search()
Dim Task As String

Me.Refresh

Task = "SELECT * FROM Table WHERE DateDiff('m', [Training], Date()) > 24 And [Active Employee] = True"

DoCmd.ApplyFilter Task

End Sub
```

Surely, I imagine I am missing something that tells it where to place the results? Any ideas? I am rather new to MS-ACCESS.

Comment: I have never used ApplyFilter. You can set RecordSource or RowSource properties with a SELECT sql statement. Or you can set form Filter property with the criteria from the WHERE clause. Review http://allenbrowne.com/ser-62.html. But why are you using code when the criteria is static? Just set the listbox RowSource property with this SQL statement in design. Really should name table something more informative than Table.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. The name `Table` was used for simplicity in the question. I guess I see coding being something that can be used all the time as complexity increases, as opposed to using RowSource and such. I'll try what you have mentioned. Again, I am new to SQL and MS-ACCESS. Just trying to be elegant :)

Comment: Are you trying to change the listbox from a non-filtered to a filtered list? Then yes, code could be used to set its RowSource property.

Comment: Nope, your method works just fine. Simple is golden. If you have time, please format your first comment to an answer for me to accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you want to change the listbox RowSource from a non-filtered to filtered list during runtime, just set the RowSource property in design instead of using VBA.

Comment: This worked perfectly, and was a far simpler solution.